# WPF Button Styling Trigger

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm stuck with Styles in WPF.  I need the background gradient to change when the user hovers their mouse over the button, but I cannot figure out how to go about the change.  This is the code I have so far:

```
    <Style x:Key="Button_Green" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#387f38" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB75B" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF449B44" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB75B" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF398239" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The mouse cursor changes properly, but the background gradient does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the target of your setter to the `Border` element that you defined in your `ControlTemplate`. Currently, it is targeting the `Background` property of the `Button` itself, which is hidden by your custom `ControlTemplate`.

```
<Style x:Key="Button_Green" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="MyBackgroundElement" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#387f38" BorderThickness="1">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB75B" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF449B44" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyBackgroundElement" Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB75B" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF398239" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Here, I added a `x:Name` property to the `Border` element so that it can be referenced with the `TargetName` property on the `Setter`.

Comment: I get this error: "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter."

Comment: Also, If I put this code in Application.xmal (it was in its own resource dictionary) I get this error: "The property 'TargetName' does not represent a valid target for the 'Setter' because an element named 'MyBackgroundElement' was not found. Make sure that the target is declared before any Setters, Triggers or Conditions that use it."

Comment: I think you need to change the Style trigger to be a template trigger as a part of the ControlTemplate.

I don't think a parent Style has knowledge of elements created in a child template.

Comment: Of course, `Trigger`s acting on elements in a `ControlTemplate` need to be defined in the scope of that template. Thanks for that, Steve!

Answer (score 0):

Change this snippet from the template

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#387f38" BorderThickness="1">
   <Border.Background>
       <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
           <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB75B" Offset="0" />
           <GradientStop Color="#FF449B44" Offset="1" />
       </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Border.Background>
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

To this (the important part is `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`):

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#387f38" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">       
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

And then add an additional setter to your style like this:

```
<Setter Property="Background">
  <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
          <GradientStop Color="#FF5BB75B" Offset="0" />
          <GradientStop Color="#FF449B44" Offset="1" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```