# WPF buttons (image & label) shadowing

Tags: wpf, image, button, label, shadow

I want to create buttons which have a image and a text included and get a nice shadowing. Particularly, I want the image and label have a light grey shadowing, but when moving the mouse over the button I'd like a kind of blue shadowing. Moving away sets it back to light grey. I would need some help as I just can't figure out how to achive it (I'm new to WPF).

The Buttons looks like ...

```
<Button>
   <Button.Content>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <Image Source="Images/preferences-system.png" />
         <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Settings</Label>
      </StackPanel>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

The Canvas goes ...

```
<Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF349EBC">
   <Canvas.Resources>

      <DropShadowEffect x:Key="dropMouseOverShadow" Color="#FFD9EDF3" Opacity="80" Direction="270" />
      <DropShadowEffect x:Key="dropLightShadow" Color="LightGrey" Opacity="10" Direction="270" BlurRadius="20" />

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                     <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                     </Border>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropMouseOverShadow}" />
                        </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style.Setters>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Style.Setters>
           <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropLightShadow}" />
         </Style.Setters>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>                  
     </Style>

     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Style.Setters>
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
           <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
           <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Gill Sans MT" />
           <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropLightShadow}" />
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}" />
           </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>

 </Canvas.Resources>
```

What I get is a light grey shadowing on image and labels on begin. Moving the mouse over the button the grey and light blue get mixed. When moving further on the image it gets the light blue only. The same goes for the label.

How can I achive switching the shadowning to light blue when I mouse over the button and not the image and label itself? Anyone an idea or an completly other approach?

Comment: Did you try BorderBrush? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777423/wpf-button-styling-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the LightGray `Effect` to the `ContentPresenter`. Then on the `IsMouseOver` Trigger, set the `Effect` property of the `ContentPresenter` to the blue `Effect`.

NOTE: Accomplish this by setting the `x:Name` attribute of the `ContentPresenter`, then accessing the `ContentPresenter` by name via the `Setter` using `TargetName`.

NOTE: Remove the various other `Effect` settings in the styles of the child elements. Applying the `Effect` to the `ContentPresenter` causes the child elements to inherit the `Effect`.

```
<Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF349EBC">
   <Canvas.Resources>

  <DropShadowEffect x:Key="dropMouseOverShadow" Color="#FFD9EDF3" Opacity="80" Direction="270" />
  <DropShadowEffect x:Key="dropLightShadow" Color="LightGrey" Opacity="10" Direction="270" BlurRadius="20" />

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                 <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp" Effect="{StaticResource dropLightShadow}"/>
                 </Border>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                       <Setter TargetName="cp" Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropMouseOverShadow}" />
                    </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style.Setters>
  </Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Style.Setters>
       <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
       <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Gill Sans MT" />
    </Style.Setters>
 </Style>
```