# Corner-rounded flat button in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am designing a UI with WPF having a rounded flat button. I wrote following code for this kind of button:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Background="DarkCyan"
        CornerRadius="4"
        Height="35"
        Width="75">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                    Content="Enter"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="DarkCyan"
                    Foreground="White"/>
</Border>
```

This button's style is exactly what I need. But at runtime, when the mouse moves to the button, it is not rounded anymore. It is a rectangle with same size. In fact, the button overflows the border. So I added `padding` to the border like this:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Background="DarkCyan"
        CornerRadius="4"
        Height="35"
        Width="75"
        Padding="2">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                    Content="Enter"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="DarkCyan"
                    Foreground="White"/>
</Border>
```

In this case, button in `hoover mode` does not overflow the border anymore, But it is still rectangle and so button’s color (In `hoover mode`) differs in this rectangle and other spaces of border. So unluckily it is not useful yet.

Now my question is: Is there any way to build a corner-rounded flat button (like the one I mentioned) that marked space in moving onto the button would be exactly the corner rounded space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Button Styling Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777423/wpf-button-styling-trigger)

Comment: Not strictly a 1:1 duplication, but what you need is to override the hover style of the button.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably down to the `VisualStateManager` for the button which is changing the style when the mouse is hovering over the button. I would suggest using a `Style` instead.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="FlatButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="4">
                     <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: Excuse me, But I am very new to WPF (I began it today). can you please tell me where should I write styles?

Comment: You can write them inside the `Resources` element for your Window/Parent Element. Check [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/resources/) out.

Comment: not perfect solution .. it shows error for me at x:key ,"The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary". in wpf"